# Leitura em blocos não avanço com read.csv. Como corrigir?

Tags: r

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte código para ler um arquivo gigante que não cabe a memoria.

```
library(dplyr)

arq_grande <- file("dados2014.csv", "r")
tam_chunk <- 1e2
df1 <- read.csv(arq_grande, nrows = 10, header = T, sep = ",", dec = ".")
df_filtrado <- df1 %>% filter(TP_SEXO == 'M')
write.table(df_filtrado, "sexoM.csv", row.names = F, sep = ",", dec = ".")

nrow <- 1

repeat {
   df <- read.csv(arq_grande, header=FALSE, col.names = names(df1), nrows = tam_chunk)
   cat("Read", nrow(df), "rows\n")
if (nrow(df) == 0)
   break
df_filtrado <- df1 %>% filter(TP_SEXO == 'M')
write.table(df_filtrado, "sexoM.csv", append = T, col.names = F,       row.names = F, sep = ",", dec = ".")
}
close(arq_grande)
```

O problema com ele é que não avança na leitura. Fica só repetindo as 10 primeiras linhas sem parar.

A escrita parece que está funcionando.

Comment: Perceba que está nrows = 10, não é isso?

Comment: Você não tem nada que faça com que sejam lidas as linhas de 10 em 10, sempre são lidas as primeiras 10 linhas. Você pode tentar usar o argumento `skip` e um contador para registrar quantas linhas já leu. Na realidade, esta não é a melhor maneira de lidar com esse problema, existem abordagens muito mais elegantes e provavelmente eficientes. Veja as respostas desta pergunta: [Estratégias para analisar bases de dados muito grandes em R (que não caibam na memória RAM)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30631/22235)

Comment: Acho que as respostas dessa pergunta também podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108729/filtrar-aquivo-csv-de-5gb-no-r/109028#109028

Comment: @Molx Quando você lê arquivos de uma conexão, como no código que o André está usando (com o  `file(...)`), as linhas são lidas de forma sequencial mesmo sem indicar o argumento `skip`. @AndréOliveira o seu código está correto. Tem certeza que não tem nenhum problema com o seu arquivo?

Comment: Na verdade, acabei de encontrar o erro! Dentro do laço de `repeat`, você tem que usar `df_filtrado <- df %>% filter(TP_SEXO == 'M')` ao invés de `df_filtrado <- df1 %>% filter(TP_SEXO == 'M')`, o problema é o **df1** que é o banco de dados usando apenas para ler as primeiras linhas.

Comment: @DanielFalbel Eu honestamente não sabia disso... Mas ainda suspeito que outras abordagens devem ser melhores, então metade do comentário ainda vale. :)

Comment: Eu daria uma olhada em duas opções que me parecem mais simples... Uma é utilizar a função read.csv.sql do pacote sqldf para já trazer os dados filtrados. E outra, que se vc somente quer separar os registros por sexo, vc consegue fazer via linha de comando, com awk, grep e afins. Ex: http://superuser.com/questions/827539/grep-to-filter-gigantic-csv-file

Comment: @DanielFalbel acho que você poderia colocar como resposta o erro encontrado

Comment: @CarlosCinelli acredito que a pergunta deveria ser fechada, na verdade. A correção de um erro de digitação é improvável de ajudar mais alguém, não acha?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pre-processar arquivos grandes de texto no R](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35469/pre-processar-arquivos-grandes-de-texto-no-r)